# How to check network connectivity in android with out using activity

Tags: android-intent

How to check network connectivity in android with out using activity, check it from business object package.

public class DataProviderFactory {

```
public IDataProvider getDataProvider() 
{

     //check for the internet connection, if exist 

    boolean connection_exist=isNetworkAvailable();





}


private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
          = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    return activeNetworkInfo != null;
}
```

but its working well in Activities.But I want to check it from the businuss object package, that is inside a class without using activities.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a `Context` into the class and use that to get the `SystemService`.